# Java: Keep executing if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, time, execution

I have an if statement which evaluates the time since the program has begun running and if the time is above a certain threshold, does something. I want this if statement to be checked throughout the whole time the program is running while at the same time have the program continue execution. How would I go about doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: Spawn a new `Thread` - pass it a `Runnable` with your code in a loop. Take a look at the [Concurrency Lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: Not sure if there's a good online tutorial, but [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601) is an awesome book for learning about threading in Java.

Comment: If you want something to happen after a certain interval, it would be best to use a threaded timer. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html. That way the program will execute your logic directly after the set time has elapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). With that, you don't need the `if` logic; you can just use the `firstTime` argument when scheduling a [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
};
// schedule the task to be run every 100ms (0.1 sec),
// starting after "threshold" milliseconds have past
timer.schedule(task, threshold, 100);
```

It's not clear from your description if you want to repeatedly "do something" once the time threshold has been exceeded, or if you just want to wait until a certain time has passed and then "do something" once. The above code is for the repeating case. For a one-shot occurrence at some future time, change the last line to:

```
timer.schedule(task, threshold);
```

If you're using Swing, you should use a Swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) rather than a java.util.Timer. See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more info.

EDIT: Your comment clarified things a bit. It's fairly easy to do what you described:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    private final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < threshold) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
};
// schedule the task to be run every 100ms (0.1 sec), starting immediately
timer.schedule(task, 0, 100);
```

Note that "do something" and "do something else" can be method calls to an enclosing class.

A cleaner approach might be to define several `TimerTask`s that are scheduled to execute at different times. The "something else" task that triggers an exception can be scheduled for one-time execution at the threshold time. You can also cancel individual tasks and you can even schedule a task that will cancel another task.

Comment: I'm sorry let me clarify. I want the run() method to execute until the time expires, in which case the program will do something else (likely throw an exception). Is there a way to specify this via the timer?

Comment: @user760220 - This is easy to do. I expanded my answer to show one approach.

Comment: Is there a way to have the run() method only occur once?

Comment: @user760220 - Does my last paragraph address this issue? You can use a `Timer` to run a `TimerTask` once at a set future time. If you want to loop and wait inside a `run()` method that is called only once, then you'll have to roll your own logic with a `Thread`. However, I don't see any advantage to that.